# Do we want to participate in Winter Bash 2013 (gravatar hats)

Tags: discussion

From the e-mail I received:

"Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users earn “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar can “wear”. We track everyone’s progress earning hats in a leaderboard..."

Comment: Due to overwhelming response, I have filled out the form to make it happen.

Answer (score 8):

**Sounds like fun!**

It may be a good way to get more consistent participation on the site.

Comment: I'm all for it.  It was a little bit of a bummer that we missed out last year.  It's totally meaningless, but totally fun!!

Comment: Agreed! Lets stir things up here a bit.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about hats is that we can't keep them all year. ;)  Bring on the hats!!!

Comment: My hats off to you fine folks, let us all look dashing in a derby as the holidays commence!